# how to restrict a Data to display in a row in datatable in JSF

Tags: jsf, datatable

There is any possible to restrict the data display in the datable based on c:if .

Let say

Output shown now:

```
Startdate     end date   status    Edit

2012-02-02    2012-03-02 Waiting   edit

2012-02-03    2012-03-04 Approved   edit
```

Output Expected:

```
Startdate     end date   status    Edit

2012-02-02    2012-03-02 Waiting   edit

2012-02-03    2012-03-04 Approved
```

When the status is Waiting then the edit link should be shown.when it is rejected or approved then the edit link should not be shown

This is my Xhtml file.

```
           <h:form>
      <h:dataTable value="#{employeeleave}" var="e"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
            columnClasses="order-table-odd-column,order-table-even-column"
        >

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Start Date
            </f:facet>
                #{e.startDate}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                End Date
            </f:facet>
                #{e.endDate}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Reason
            </f:facet>
                #{e.reason}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Status
            </f:facet>
                #{e.status}
        </h:column>
            <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            Edit
        </f:facet>
        <c:if test="${e.status == 'Waiting'}">
        <p:commandLink value="Edit" action="editLeave" id="editleave" >
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{e}" target="#{employeeDetails.employeeLeaveSelected}" />
        </p:commandLink>
        </c:if>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>  
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSTL tags doesn't work that way. They runs during view build time, not during view render time which is what you seem to expect. The `${e}` is **not** available during view build time and would in your particular case thus always resolve to `null`.

You need to use the JSF component's `rendered` attribute instead.

Replace

```
<c:if test="${e.status == 'Waiting'}">
    <p:commandLink value="Edit" action="editLeave" id="editleave" >
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{e}" target="#{employeeDetails.employeeLeaveSelected}" />
    </p:commandLink>
</c:if>
```

by

```
<p:commandLink value="Edit" action="editLeave" id="editleave" rendered="#{e.status == 'Waiting'}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{e}" target="#{employeeDetails.employeeLeaveSelected}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)